# How can I wrap a soundwave plot into a circle or radial?

Tags: python, audio, plotly, radial, soundwaves

My first ever post, and I’m a relatively new coder.

I’m interested in data visualisation, and I’m trying to create a poster that can depict a Soundwave in a circular format.

I’ve tried to attach a photoshop mock-up of what I’m aiming for, but I’m new and so I don’t have enough status points for images (will try and host elsewhere and link back to a URL)

Is there a way to take a plot and wrap into a circular format directly from a plotting library? I’ve searched high and low for the right code, but can’t seem to pin down something that works for sound wave plots.

I could export a normal wave plot and “wrap to polar” in photoshop, or some other Python code that wraps “images” or plots using a different library, but I’m wondering if I’m missing something obvious with built-in plotting options.

I’ve searched the matplotlib documentation (perhaps not very well, I am new to coding) and can only find references to circular bar plots and radar charts. Not found a way that stands out (to me) how to take any similar arguments and apply to a Soundwave.

Bonus points if the same could be done for spectrographs! Thank you!

[image]

Many thanks in advance, all guidance gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should, at a minimum, include the code you've attempted to accomplish this task and what went wrong. This forum is really for *help*, not so much *do it for me*.

However, if you had *any* line data, you could make it a polar graph.

To make this happen in Plotly, if the amplitude is on the y-axis, you need to scale the x-axis values to a range of 0-360 (like degrees in a circle).

This is a basic UDF to rescale data, where old and new lows and highs are the ranges of the current scale and the future scale.

```
def newScale(oldLow, oldHigh, newLow, newHigh, arr):
    """change scale, where `arr` is a numeric value to be rescaled"""
    return(newLow + (newHigh - newLow) * (arr - oldLow)/(oldHigh - oldLow))
```

It might look something like this:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# - import data

# x_data =...
# y_data =...

# - rescale x_data

orig_min = min(x_data)
orig_max = max(x_data)

x_rescaled = [newScale(orig_min, orig_max, 0, 360, xer) for xer in x_data]

# - make a graph with data
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(r = y_data, theta = x_rescaled, mode = "lines"))

fig.show()
```

As a polar graph (using the code above) in both (the right graph has 1/3 the data)

[image] [image]

This is what it *would* have looked like as a line graph:

[image]

If you wanted concentric rings of audio data like your image, you would scale the y-axis, as well. The scale you would use depends on the data, where the goal is that the scales do not overlap.

Comment: Many thanks. I take the point about contributing code, and will do so in future. I was at a total loss as to where to start with this one and so didn’t have any code except plotting a “straight” wave. I can see that “Scatterpolar” is the keyword that could have helped me zone in on the issue, and I think I’m following the logic for taking the values and mapping them to degrees in a circle (theta)

Thank you again. I will endeavour to update this post with the code for any further experimentation and / or spectrogram versions if I can adapt accordingly, hoping it’ll be useful.